# Kafka retry mechanism doesn't stop even the previous retry attempt was successful

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka retry mechanism in place which retry 2 times by waiting 30 seconds for each attempt. I noticed that even though the first retry attempt was successful, It's still retrying the second attempt. This results in generating duplicate messages in the kafka topic. Is there any way to stop Kafka to do unnecessary retries when the previous retry attempt is successful?

Here is my listener configuration

```
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SpecificRecord>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SpecificRecord> factory =
      new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(testConsumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
    SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler =
      new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
        LOGGER.error("Error while processing the record {}", exception.getCause().getMessage());
      }, new FixedBackOff(30000L, 2L));
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    return factory;
  }
```

Here is my listener logic and the flow

1. ConsumerA consumes the data from the topicA and  makes a call to microservice for the data
2. After getting  the data, Producer publishes the data to topicB
3. ConsumerB consumes the data from the topicB and makes a call to a microservice for persisting the data
4. Once data gets persisted, a new message gets published to topicB.

Consumer logic for topicA

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${test.topicA.name}",
    containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void topicListener(ConsumerRecord<String, SpecificRecord> record) {
    LOGGER.info("Consumed {} topic from partition {} ", record.topic(), record.partition());
    testService.getData(record);
  }
```

Consumer logic for topicB

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${test.topicB.name}",
    containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void topicListener(ConsumerRecord<String, SpecificRecord> record) {
    LOGGER.info("Consumed {} topic from partition {} ", record.topic(), record.partition());
     testService2.persistDetails(record);
  }
```

Comment: You need to show your configuration and listener code. If you mean your listener is publishing to another topic then, yes, you will see duplicates if the failure is after the send. You need to use transactions to avoid this, so that the publish is rolled back.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have added listener code and the flow of my application. Could look at it and navigate me on why I'm seeing duplicate events on some instances even though the previous retry was successful

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking; try enabling DEBUG logging to see if it helps you.

Comment: @GaryRussell I did try, but I couldn't able to replicate the issue as it's happening occasionally. Any reasons for these occasional third retry even though the previous retry was successful? Does enabling transaction would fix the issue?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the logs and understanding what happened.